# changing position / re-arranging records in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

i have this database

```
id  user_id auction_id no_of_bids bid_value timestamp
110     236        435          3         6 2015-11-10 12:40:21
111     238        435          4         6 2015-11-10 12:46:33
```

i want to re arrange the order of these records, for example in the current situation, i want 238 to come before 236, is there a query to execute the said operation?
i know about changing column orders, but i believe records can not be re arranged like that. 
is there a way or query where i can re arrange the records and let 238 come before 236, or, be at the top of records?

Comment: a simple select query, 
select * from psf_bidomatic

Comment: well that's pretty obvious, i was looking for a query to perform this action in my code. PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `order by`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by (t.user_id = 238) desc;
```

This will put 238 first.

Comment: (or perhaps just order by user_id desc - the question isn't really clear enough. Anyway @FaizanShah, either way, it's pretty obvious too, isn't it ;-)  )